# What's a good way to remove all of the subviews of a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view and I need to reload the contents often while my app is running. Right now, I'm using the following line of code to remove the subviews before adding them back again:

```
[scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Should I be using the following instead?

```
scrollView.subviews = nil;
```

For some reason, the (first) above line of code seems to crash the app every 16 times it is run. Am I leaking memory somewhere? The following method takes an array of views, the scroller (which is a constant) and the direction.

**Edit:**

```
- (void)loadViews:(NSArray *)views IntoScroller:(UIScrollView *)scroller withDirection:(NSString *)direction{
//Set up the scrollView

[scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

if([direction isEqualToString:@"horizontal"]){
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:[views count]] floatValue], scrollView.frame.size.height);
}else if([direction isEqualToString:@"vertical"]){
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height * [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:[views count]] floatValue]);
}

for (int i=0; i<[[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:[views count]] intValue]; i++) {

    [[[views objectAtIndex:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] unsignedIntValue]] view] setFrame:scrollView.frame];

    if([direction isEqualToString:@"horizontal"]){
        [[[views objectAtIndex:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] unsignedIntValue]] view] setFrame:CGRectMake(i * [[views objectAtIndex:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] unsignedIntValue]] view].frame.size.width, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];//CGRectMake(i * announcementView.view.frame.size.width, -scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    }else if([direction isEqualToString:@"vertical"]){
        [[[views objectAtIndex:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] unsignedIntValue]] view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, i * [[views objectAtIndex:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] unsignedIntValue]] view].frame.size.height, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    }

    [scrollView addSubview:[[views objectAtIndex:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] unsignedIntValue]] view]];
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example that you gave is the correct way to remove subviews from a `UIScrollView`.

```
[scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Setting `subviews` to `nil` effectively nils-out the collection object managing the subviews, thereby making it impossible to add new subviews.

Comment: I'm still leaking memory or something. Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: Okay, so every time I want to reset the subviews, how do I do so?

Comment: @Moshe Just invoke the method as you described, that's all. You cannot reset the array itself, when you call `removeFromSuperview:` it should do it for you.

Comment: @Jacb - Thanks, I'm not sure what's going on here though.

Comment: Also just a quick simplifying note -- "[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] unsignedIntValue] is tautological -- you can just say "i" instead. [views objectAtIndex: i]   would work just as well!

Comment: @AndyMilburn - Yes, but you get a warngin about using a variable without a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to remove all the sub views from the scroll view:

```
for(UIView *subview in [scrollview  subviews]) 
        {
         [subview removeFromSuperview];

        }
```